# Select Two different values in the same column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

## QUERY

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE (
`category` = 'a'
AND `category` = 'b'
)
```

## MySQL

```
products
---
id      sku     category
-------------------------
1       34343   a
2       32523   d
3       23234   b
4       23433   b
5       23442   c
```

I want to return A and B

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE (
`category` = 'a'
OR `category` = 'b'
)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE
`category` IN ('a', 'b')
```

You can use IN clause to replace many OR conditions. IN simply checks whether a value is within a set of values.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the OR operator because with AND you select where category is A and B but you have to select where category are A or B

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE (
`category` = 'a' OR `category` = 'b'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `category` in('a','b')
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE 
`category` in ('a', 'b')

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

> SELECT c1
>   FROM table
>   WHERE c2 IN (1,2,3,4)
>   GROUP BY c1
>   HAVING COUNT(c2)=4;